# Routing: in AngularJS or .NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, routes

We are starting a major upgrade of a large WebForms application. The logic will be split between AngularJS on the front end and .NET MVC on the back end. What are the criteria about where to put routing? I can put it in RouteConfig.cs on the server and have .NET to be responsible for routing; or I can use ng-route on the client, and use only WebApi calls to the server. 
I see pros and cons both ways, and I was wondering if anybody has any decision criteria. Or some articles that I missed (Google has plenty on implementing the routes; but not on the decision to pick one over another).

Comment: No other articles, but I would say it's a matter of where you want to handle more state control. As a larger single page application, it's all on the client side.  As a developer on a current split site with angular, ASP, & MVC, we can't just do one.  So the issue is that some developers think one way and other think the other way, which creates issues.  But we are not afforded the ability to fully switch either.

Comment: @KnowHowSolutions - you don't make it easier :) It's a very large application; I am actually afraid to load all .js controllers. Looking to web components to load things dynamically. On the other hand, I want to make the application as responsive as possible - so handling the state seems more logical on the client.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would argue for full separation of concerns, so routing on the client. Doing the routing on the client puts the client in control of what is being displayed. The server would only serve the raw data via rest.

This also allows you more flexibility in the future as well. Say in 2 year you want to ditch Angular for the next new client framework. All you need are client developers to implement the UI calling the existing endpoints, the server code would not need to be touched. Want to move away from .NET backend? No problem, just implement the endpoint in the new framework, not client could would need to be changed.

Comment: I don't think we will make radical changes in 2 years - it took over 10 years to move away from very poorly written WebForms. But your point is well taken! I was leaning towards client as well - but now I have you to blame if something goes wrong :D

Answer (score 0):

You should use both as your application is large.

let say your screens are divide on the bases of rule.

When Admin will login you will load all files related to that functionality and after that take benefit of ng-view and make that functionality as a single page app.

So in this way you don't need to load all files once. by ng-view you can also share data between different screens.

Comment: Admin is a separate application, running on a different address. Equally big ;)